# Error in gfconv (Galois field function) in Matlab

Tags: matlab, galois-field

I am trying to multiply a hexdecimal value `AA` by 2 in the galois field using the `gfconv(a,b)` function of Matlab, the console returns to me an error saying: "The input elements must be binary.", but my two elements are binary

```
a=hexToBinaryVector('AA');
b=de2bi(2);
c=gfconv(a,b);
disp(c);
```

The error code:

```
Error using gfconv_mex
The input elements must be binary.

Error in gfconv (line 120)
        c = gfconv_mex(varargin{:});

Error in test(line 3)
c=gfconv(a,b);
```

Any idea how to solve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not doing all the code here, but here's the steps that I would take to solve it.

**Problem**

It's in binary form, but `b` is a vector of binary numbers.

**Solution**

1. Look up https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mat2str.html
2. Convert your vector to the string
3. Parse the string and pull out the ones and zeros
4. use str2num to convert back to a number: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/str2num.html

Try that and see if it works.

**Note - Expansion of step 3:**

if we have variable `a = '[0+11]';`, we can select individual characters from the string like:

```
 a(3)
ans = '+'
a(4)
ans = '1'
a(1)
and = '['
```

Therefore, you can parse the string with a loop"

```
for n = 1 : length(a)
    if a(n) == '1' || a(n) == '0'
        str(n) = a(n);
    end
end
```

Finally, convert the string:

```
num = str2num(str);
```

done

Comment: I really don't understand your solution, could you be more specific in the item 3?

Comment: See **note** above

Comment: After a few attempts I managed to implement and it worked, thank you!